# sql left join with subselection in comma-delimited field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to take the column `Ngr` from table `groups` WHERE the marks of the students are bad(=2) in more than two subjects and the number of these students are the half from the group:

```
    SELECT Ngr 
    FROM subject 
        LEFT JOIN groups ON (subject.Ngr = groups.Ngr) 
    WHERE....
```

and here I can't continue

thanks for your future advice!

groups:

```
| Ngr | Name_of_speciality |
----------------------------
|  1  |  Physics           |
..........................
```

subject:

```
| Ngr | Name   | marks                     |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  | Physics|2,2,3,3,5,5,5,4,3,2,2,5,2,4|
...........................................
```

Good luck!

Comment: `DESCRIBE subject;` and `DESCRIBE groups;` please. Also, please define 'marks of the students are bad'

Comment: you would have to use LIKE; but wouldn't it be better to redesign your tables to have each mark be a seperate row?

Comment: @Luceos, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment;

> you would have to use LIKE; but wouldn't it be better to redesign your tables to have each mark be a seperate row?
>
> @Luceos, how can I do that?

it depends on your table format; you duplicate Physics in your table, why's that? You have a group called Physics and a subject called Physics, should that be an exam name like Physics 1? Then if you dont want to connect marks to students you can make an auto increment column for primary id:

```
| id  | Ngr | Name   | mark                     |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  | Physics|2                          |
-------------------------------------------
|  2  |  1  | Physics|5                          |
...........................................
```

Etcetera.. This way you can select by mark = 2 or mark <= 2 and get results back in the join.